# Does Skorohod Dudley Wichura theorem imply Continuous Mapping Theorem?

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems, strong-convergence

The continuous mapping theorem (CMT) asserts that for $g$ a.e. continuous on the support of $X$,

1. $X_n\overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow}X\implies g(X_n)\overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow}g(X).$
2. $X_n\overset{p}{\rightarrow}X\implies g(X_n)\overset{p}{\rightarrow}g(X).$
3. $X_n\overset{d}{\rightarrow}X\implies g(X_n)\overset{d}{\rightarrow}g(X).$

Skorohod Dudley Wichura (SDW) theorem, as I understand, says that if $X_n\overset{d}{\rightarrow}X$, then  there is a probability space where $Y_n,Y$ are defined such that $Y_n\overset{d}{=}X_n,Y\overset{d}{=}X,Y_n\overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow}Y.$

Suppose we know 1. to hold.  Can SDW be used to prove 2. of CMT?

I am able to show SDW proves 3. of CMT as follows:
\begin{align*}
X_n\overset{d}{\rightarrow}X&\implies \exists Y_n\overset{d}{=}X_n,Y\overset{d}{=}X,\text{ s.t. } Y_n\overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow}Y\\
&\implies g(Y_n)\overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow}g(Y)\quad \text{by 1.}\\
&\implies \underbrace{g(Y_n)}_{\overset{d}{=}g(X_n)} \overset{d}{\rightarrow} \underbrace{g(Y)}_{\overset{d}{=}g(X)}\quad \text{since } \overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow} \implies \overset{d}{\rightarrow}\\
&\implies g(X_n)\overset{d}{\rightarrow}g(X).
\end{align*}

However, I am not sure how to extend this to use SDW to prove 2. of CMT since
$\underbrace{g(Y_n)}_{\overset{d}{=}g(X_n)} \overset{p}{\rightarrow} \underbrace{g(Y)}_{\overset{d}{=}g(X)}\not \Rightarrow  g(X_n)\overset{p}{\rightarrow}g(X).$